# SQLite Error on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sqlite

So I'm new at programming the Windows Phone and brand new at SQLite. I am trying to add a database to the Connect the Dots application from Microsoft that accesses the Microsoft Band: https://github.com/Azure/connectthedots/tree/master/Devices/DirectlyConnectedDevices/WindowsPhoneAndBand

Ive followed several tutorials on setting up a sample database application for the Windows Phone, but I have come up with 2 debug errors that I cant seem to find the answer to.

When I run the program in the simulator in VS2015 I get the following 2 messages:
1. SQLite 3.8.11.1 needs Microsoft.VClibs Version 12.0.
2. SQLite needs sqlite3.dll and cant find the file.

My thought is that I am using the wrong SQLite version. Currently I am using the newest SQLite for Windows Phone with the sqlite-net API.  Anyone know how to correctly create a database on a windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Download SQLite for windows phone 8.1
   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b
2. Then Add a reference to SQLite and VCLibs.
   [image]
3. Go to package manager console then: `Install-Package sqlite-net`

Comment: Ok, so this is where I am confused. I have already installed SQLite for Phone 8.1, and i have installed sqlite-net. I can add a reference to SQLite for WP 8.1.   However, I dont have a reference for the Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package. Is this something I can get from Nuget?

Comment: Ok so for anyone else confused about VCLibs 12 - you need to add the Visual Studio 2013 SDK - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758

Comment: Did this answer your question?